# Why in Top N query scenario Oracle does not use index?

Tags: indexing, oracle11g

Want to get the latest top 5 trade date from table(5077913 records),

```
select trade_date from (select distinct trade_date from BOND_DAY_QUO order by trade_date desc) a where rownum <=5;
```

and there is an unique index: `TRADE_DATE, BOND_ID`

but when I check the explain plan, found it does not use this index and do the full table scan
[image]

Why it is not full index scan?

Comment: Is your TRADE_DATE column nullable?

Comment: @Boneist Yes it's nullable and when added query condition: `where trade_date is not null`  it changed to `FAST FULL SCAN`